# How to fail 7Zip when no files were added?

Tags: 7-zip

I use 7Zip in batch process under Windows OS.

If I use "a" command (to add files to new archive file that doesn't exist) 7Zip  still succeeds even if the file I explicitly specified to be added doesn't exist - ZIP file is created but is has no files inside it.

Is there an additional 7Zip command line option that would cause 7Zip to fail when the file I want to be added doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking if the file exists before calling 7Zip.

```
if exist {insert file name here} (
rem file exists
) else (
rem file doesn't exist
)
```

From [How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this and probably will end up doing it but was hoping to avoid additional step.